# Value Radio Button não passa via Post php

Tags: php

Apenas dois radio button.

```
$faturamento_tipo_post = $_POST['faturamento_tipo'];
if (isset($faturamento_tipo_post) && $faturamento_tipo_post == "cl") {
$tipo_faturamento = 1;
}
elseif (isset($faturamento_tipo_post) && $faturamento_tipo_post == "co") {
$tipo_faturamento = 0;
}
else
 {
$tipo_faturamento = "Houve um erro na busca do faturamento tipo";
echo '<br>'.$tipo_faturamento.'<br>';

exit;
}


    <label class="radio">
    <input type="radio" name="faturamento_tipo" value="cl"  />
    Cliente
</label>
<label class="radio">
    <input type="radio" name="faturamento_tipo" value="co"  />
    Cortesia
</label>
```

Não funciona, sempre recebo a última mensagem, a variável esta vazia.

Comment: Poste o código do formulário

Comment: Dá um print_r($_POST); pra ver o que aparece.. se vem os retornos.

Comment: Justamente isso que fiz, e não me retorna nada dos radios

Comment: Estão dentro de um <form> ?

Comment: Coloque a linha também do <form> para ver se não faltou nada nele.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elaborei a função de exemplo: Creio que com isto resolverá seu problema. 
Porém, faça a verificação se o $_POST está vindo corretamente do seu formulário.

## Código PHP

```
#Verificação do Tipo de Faturamento
function verificaTipo($tipo){

    switch($tipo){

        default: 
            $tipo_faturamento = "Nenhum tipo";
            break;

        case 'cl':
            $tipo_faturamento = 1;
            break;

        case 'co':
            $tipo_faturamento = '0';
            break;

    }

    #Retorno
    return $tipo_faturamento;


}


#Saida para o HTML  
if(!empty($_POST))
echo verificaTipo($_POST['faturamento_tipo']);
```

## Formulário

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<? echo $PHP_SELF;?>" name="formulario" method="post">
    <label class="radio">
        <input type="radio" name="faturamento_tipo" value="cl"  />
            Cliente
        </label>
    <label class="radio">
        <input type="radio" name="faturamento_tipo" value="co"  />
            Cortesia
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>
```

Comment: Falto o `method` que se omito é `get` por padrão. :P

Comment: Alterei, e também inclui uma nova linha, e testei aqui no meu localhost pra ver, e deu certo. :) @rray Agradeço a dica.

Comment: @AndréBaill testei com tua função, não me imprime nada, o meu <form> estava exatamente igual ao seu exemplo, o que pode ser isso?

Comment: Poste seu formulário completo, com as tags e etc... Para que possamos analisar também.

Comment: Verifique se está incluido o método do formulário: method="post"

Comment: Sim, estou o form estava funcionando normalmente, não sei o que houve

Comment: Você conseguiu verificar se está chegando o post? Ou ao menos se está entrando na função que lhe indiquei?

Comment: Resolvi, o problema por incrivel que pareça, eram umas div que estavam com fechamento </div>, dentro do <form>, mas, as div foram abertas antes do form.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25979/discussion-between-andre-baill-and-snniffer).

Answer (score 1):

Limpe a informação que vem do formulário:

```
$faturamento_tipo_post = trim(strip_tags($_POST['faturamento_tipo']));
```

Algumas vezes podem vir espaços em branco e ou tags html.

**trim**: remove os espaços em branco tanto a esquerda quanto a direita da string.

**strip_tags**: remove as tags html.